# Number of ways of choosing $3$ numbers from $\{1,2,...,15\}$ with replacement will result in a sum of $15$ (order matters)

Tags: combinatorics

I know the answer is $\binom{14}{2}$, but I'm not sure how to get there. Could anyone explain the process? I just listed them out and added them.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_k$ denote the result of the $k$th choice.  Then we wish to find the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 15$$
in the positive integers.  A particular choice corresponds to where to place two addition signs between successive ones in a row of $15$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 7$, $x_2 = 3$, and $x_3 = 5$.  Since there are $14$ spaces that lie between successive ones in a row of $15$ ones, the number of solutions is equal to the number of ways we can choose two of those fourteen spaces in which to place an addition sign, which is 
$$\binom{14}{2}$$
By similar argument, you can show that the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$